# Docker installed the wrong version of Python despite specifying the version

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

This is the part of my Dockerfile that installs Python and my code's dependencies.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  python3.8 \
  python3-pip \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

# Update Python with the required packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The image gets created and then when I ran the code I got this error back

```
q9zp213vt4-algo-1-cqgxl | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
```

This message alerted me to the use of Python 3.6 and when I checked my image's Python version using the CLI I could indeed see it was the default Python version `3.6.9`.

Apologies for this basic question, but I'm not familiar with working with Docker and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The Base image of `Ubuntu` cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the specific Python 3 version. `RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` only tells Ubuntu to use the default Python 3 instead of Python 2, but not which Python 3. On my computer, `python3` is linked to `python3.10`. You can forcibly replace the version with  `RUN ln -fs /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I made the changes and recreated the image. However, the Python version still shows as `3.6.9`

Comment: This is how I confirmed the Python version. First I did `cd usr/bin`. Then typed in `python` and the Python terminal came up along with the version number

Comment: Apologies. It turns out I was checking the Python version on the wrong image. My Python version has been updated. Thanks a lot!