# What is the fastest way to install python specific version in docker

Tags: python, docker, optimization, github-actions

Downloading specific version like `3.11.1` from `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/Python-3.11.1.tgz` and  installing `./configure --enable-optimizations && make install` is slow (30 - 40 mins), on GitHub actions.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:22.04 as base

USER root

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ZscalerCertificate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ZscalerCertificate.crt

RUN find /tmp -name \*.deb -exec rm {} +

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common ca-certificates &&\
    update-ca-certificates

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ gnupg unixodbc-dev openssl git &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libssl-dev \
    libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev
RUN mkdir /python && cd /python
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/Python-3.11.1.tgz
RUN tar -zxvf Python-3.11.1.tgz
RUN cd Python-3.11.1 && ls -lhR && ./configure --enable-optimizations && make install
```

What is the optimal way to install python specific version?

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the prebuilt images?  https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: @AirSquid Because, it don't have specific python versions. I need specific python version because security scanning tool (whitesource/mend) is showing some critical vulnerabilities in the latest version of python.

Comment: What about create your own image and reuse it?

Comment: @dankal444 I was thinking in similar lines, which will be the last hope, but looking for other installing options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker keeps installing the wrong version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170176/docker-keeps-installing-the-wrong-version-of-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mainstream programming languages, a standard Docker Hub image will exist for every version of it.  Older versions might not get updates including security issues in the underlying Linux distribution, but the images don't get deleted either.

```shellsession
$ docker run --rm python:3.11.1 python -V
Python 3.11.1
```

(I've very rarely run into problems where I need to pin to an exact version of a language runtime; consider whether a floating major-version tag like `python:3.11` – as of this writing, Python 3.11.4 – will meet your needs.  That will get both routine security updates and also bug-fix releases of the language.)

Comment: I need to install msodbcsql17, mssql-tools as well, in the docker image. Do you recommend multi stage, with python:3.11.1 as first stage, and ubuntu:22.04 as second stage to install other tools as needed?

Comment: *Older versions might not get updates including security issues in the underlying Linux distribution*, does that mean, the older version i.e., `3.11.1` remains as it is and the newer version `3.11.4` will get security updates and when `3.11.4` get updates, it will change to other versions like `3.11.5` or higher, is my understanding is correct?

Comment: The standard `python` image is already based on Debian and includes APT, you can install additional tools and libraries into a `python`-based image.

Comment: Though, it's a fastest way, I can't use `python:3.11.1` as base image, because it is using `debian 11` which contains many critical vulnerabilities.